# Why can't I login with newly created MySQL User?

Tags: mysql

I create a MySQL user as follows:

```
mysql> grant all privileges on *.* to mysql@'%' IDENTIFIED by 'myPassword' with grant option;                           
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)

mysql> exit;
Bye
```

Then I try to login with that newly created user but it doesn't work.

```
% mysql -u mysql -pmyPassword
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'mysql'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
%
```

Why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe localhost is special and not covered by the '%'.

Issue

```
mysql> grant all privileges on *.* to mysql@'localhost' IDENTIFIED by 'myPassword' with grant option;
```

and it should work

Comment: Yes! That worked. Thanks! I will accept your answer as soon as it lets me. :)

Comment: The solution to identify host as localhost worked but it is not clear why. I created a new user mysql command line without defining from host. and then see user looks correct in workbench with from host defined as '%'.  Then add permission to select without identifying host and flush privileges in command line. The login didn't work in workbench. I will look up the implications for IP address, localhost and '%' in the command line statements. Doing all via workbench just works. It appears workbench hides using 'localhost'.

Answer (score 6):

It seems counter-intuitive, but 'localhost' is not matched by `'%'` in MySQL.  The reason is that all `'%'` matches all TCP/IP connections, but connections from 'localhost' are mapped to the unix domain socket.

There are two possible solutions:

1. Do an extra grant for the user at 'localhost':

   ```
   mysql> grant all privileges on *.* to mysql@'localhost' IDENTIFIED by 'myPassword' with grant option;
   ```

   PS: you don't have to FLUSH PRIVILEGES after GRANT.
2. Force access via TCP/IP:

   ```
   % mysql -u mysql -pmyPassword -h 127.0.0.1
   ```